# How do I enable the selection of different types of mode of the blur tool?

Tags: gimp

I'm using GIMP 2.10.2 in Spanish so not 100% sure the english terms I use here will be 100%  correctly translated. I want to be able to set the different modes of the blur tool, now
it's set in "Normal", and the dropdownlist to select the modes is disabled. I've seen it enabled before, but I dont know what I have to do to enable it.

How do I enable the selection of different types of mode of the blur tool?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The blur tool doesn't have modes. That's why the modes are greyed out and you can't select them. What are you actually trying to do here? What kind of edit? There may be another way to do it. Can you please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/157232/edit) and provide more details, maybe an example image?  At the moment your question reads a bit like [an XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @BillyKerr . Thanks for the answer. I wanted to see if I could achieve some effect I was looking for. The question will be completely different if I edit it. I guess I'll leave this open and I'll see later if I open another question.